# Want to receive bounce back emails on my gmail account

Tags: phpmailer

I am using phpmailer class to send email from my server. Below is my code, i am able to send email with this code to valid email address. I want to receive bounce back emails on my email address farazaleem@gmail.com but i am not receiving any email when i send email to invalid email account like dsfsdfdsfsfsfsfs@rtretreert.com

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail  = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth      = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; 
$mail->Host          = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port          = 25; 
$mail->Username      = "xxxxxx@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password      = "xxxxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom('farazaleem@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject       = "Email body";
$mail->Sender = 'farazaleem@gmail.com';
$mail->MsgHTML($email_details);
$mail->AddAddress($entered_person_email, $full_name);  
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: You're doing the right thing by settings `Sender`. CC yourself on an outbound message so you can see what's actually being delivered; you may find that GoDaddy is altering your messages.

Comment: But I am using gmail account as sender and not Godaddy.

Comment: No you're not. You're using a GoDaddy mail server secureserver.net.